# Is it possible to use another retrofit call inside on a first onResponse retrofit call?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley, retrofit

Hello I'm doing an app where I need to display the last 10 videos from a youtube channel. I'm using retrofit

First I use this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={Channel name}&key={Api key}`

From that json I'm going to get the channel ID so I can use it in here and obtain the last 10 videos from a specific youtube channel:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId={channel ID}&maxResults=10&key={Api key}`

I already did the first part and I got the channel ID using retrofit.

Is it ok to use another retrofit call inside the fist onResponse retrofit call? that would be having a background thread inside a background thread or is there another way to do this?

Comment: RxJava somewhat fixes this "nesting". Though, that would require you learn a new library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue in making another retrofit call in your onResponse method.

You won't be "nesting" threads as onResponse callbacks are performed on your main Android thread. So enqueuing another call will just spin off a thread from your main thread. Also note that because of this you can't directly call execute() on your new call since you are back on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no problem, but i think it's better to bring the other call to a specific function and inside the callback of the first call you call the function.

It's better to read and debug, nested callbacks are a little messy to track bugs.